# Get object out jtable

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, jtextfield

Im trying to get an object out of a JTable and transfer it to another jform where you can edit the values. But when I want to show the variables of the object in the jform I get an nullpointerexception.

```
private void taBuyersMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
// TODO add your handling code here:
if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
    Model.TabelModel model = (Model.TabelModel) taBuyers.
            getModel();
    int row = taBuyers.getSelectedRow();
    if (row != -1) {
        int Id = (int) model.getValueAt(row, 0);
        String Name = (String) model.getValueAt(row, 1);
        String LastName = (String) model.getValueAt(row, 2);
        Date gebDate = (java.sql.Date) model.getValueAt(row, 3);
        Boolean seller = Boolean.valueOf(model.getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
        String comment = (String) model.getValueAt(row, 5);
        Person pers = new Person(Id,Name,LastName, gebDate,seller,comment);
        MakePerson person = new MakePerson();
        person.setPerson(pers);
        person.setVisible(true);
    } 
}
```

}

Here is the Person displayed when I debug i see the object and all variables are filled in.

```
    public void setPerson(Person pers) {
        teId.setText(String.valueOf((pers.getId()))); => here I get the nullpointerexception 
    }


private javax.swing.JTextField teId;
```

this is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui.scherm.Personscreen.MakePerson.setPerson(MakePerson.java:42)
    at gui.scherm.Personscreen.taBuyersMouseClicked(Personscreeb.java:176)
    at gui.scherm.Personscreen.access$000(Personscreen.java:30)
    at gui.scherm.Personscreen$1.mouseClicked(Personscreen.java:110)
```

Comment: I guess its typo `setPersoon != setPerson`

Comment: @Smit It wouldn't compile, then. Unless the OP just happens to have methods named `setPerson` and `setPersoon` which both take one argument (an instance of `Person`)

Comment: @ColinMorelli True. Thats why I said its a typo. Anyhow if you look at the stacktrace it shows `setPersoon` and method defined as `setPerson`

Comment: there are no typos i had to change this it was in dutch :)

Comment: Maybe teId is not initialized?

Comment: Are you initializing the teId variable somewhere?

Comment: That was the problem thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
private javax.swing.JTextField teId ;
```

to

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;


private JTextField teId = new JTextField();
```